# Android Studio 3.5.2 Offline setup Error: app@debug/compileClasspath

Tags: android, gradle

Help please,
After I setup and I follow this instructions:

Configure offline build dependencies

If you'd like to build your project without a network connection, 
follow the steps below to configure the IDE to use offline versions of the Android Gradle Plugin and Google Maven dependencies.

If you haven't already done so, download the offline components from the downloads page.

Download and unzip offline components

After you have downloaded the offline components, unzip their contents into the following directory, which you might need to create if it doesn’t already exist:

•   On Windows: %USER_HOME%/.android/manual-offline-m2/

•   On macOS and Linux: ~/.android/manual-offline-m2/

To update the offline components, proceed as follows:

1. Delete the content inside the manual-offline-m2/ directory.
2. Re-download the offline components.
3. Unzip the contents of the ZIP files you downloaded into the manual-offline-m2/ directory.
   Include offline components in your Gradle project
   To tell the Android build system to use the offline components you've downloaded and unzipped, you need to create a script, as described below. Keep in mind, you need to create and save this script only once, even after updating your offline components.
4. Create an empty text file with the following path and file name:
   •   On Windows: %USER_HOME%/.gradle/init.d/offline.gradle
   •   On macOS and Linux: ~/.gradle/init.d/offline.gradle
5. Open the text file and include the following script:

   def reposDir = new File(System.properties['user.home'], ".android/manual-offline-m2")

   def repos = new ArrayList()
   reposDir.eachDir {repos.add(it)
    }
   repos.sort()

   allprojects {

   buildscript {

   ```
   repositories {

     for (repo in repos) {

       maven {

         name = "injected_offline_${repo.name}"

         url = repo.toURI().toURL()

       }

     }

   }
   ```

   }
     repositories {

   ```
   for (repo in repos) {

     maven {

       name = "injected_offline_${repo.name}"

       url = repo.toURI().toURL()

     }

   }
   ```

   }

   }
6. Save the text file.

I got this errors:

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
Disable offline mode and sync project
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3.
Disable offline mode and sync project
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0.
Disable offline mode and sync project
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1.
Disable offline mode and sync project
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
Disable offline mode and sync project
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3.
Disable offline mode and sync project
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
Disable offline mode and sync project
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3.
Disable offline mode and sync project
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
Disable offline mode and sync project
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`%USER_HOME%/.android/manual-offline-m2/`.

To update these compone
`%USER_HOME%/.gradle/init.d/offline.gradle`.
2. Open the text file and include the following script:

```
def reposDir = new File(System.properties['user.home'], ".android/manual-offline-m2")
def repos = new ArrayList()
reposDir.eachDir {repos.add(it) }
repos.sort()

allprojects {
  buildscript {
    repositories {
      for (repo in repos) {
        maven {
          name = "injected_offline_${repo.name}"
          url = repo.toURI().toURL()
        }
      }
    }
  }
  repositories {
    for (repo in repos) {
      maven {
        name = "injected_offline_${repo.name}"
        url = repo.toURI().toURL()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

3. Save the text file.
4. (Optional) If you’d like to verify that the offline components are working as
   intended, remove the online repositories from your project’s `build.gradle`
   files, as shown below. After you’ve confirmed that your project builds
   correctly without these repositories, you can put them back into your
   `build.gradle` files.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Hide these repositories to test your build against
        // the offline components. You can include them again after
        // you’ve confirmed that your project builds ‘offline’.
        // google()
        // jcenter()
    }
    …
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // google()
        // jcenter()
    }
    ...
}
```