# Android Studio Error - Could not resolve androidx.core When working offline

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, build.gradle

I just began learning programming Android Apps with Kotlin in Android Studio 3.6.1 and I'm trying to work offline, so I used the instructions in this article to do so:
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#offline

but i still get these Errors when building a project and I cannot run the application or edit the interface of the application.

- ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0.
- ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0.
- ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0.
- ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0.
- ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0.
- ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0.

I tried some solutions here, but it seems like they had different versions than the one I'musing.
I also tried this link, but it didn't work, either.
[Android Studio 3.5.2 Offline setup Error: app@debug/compileClasspath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58798957/android-studio-3-5-2-offline-setup-error-appdebug-compileclasspath)

I need to solve these issues and use Android Studio offline, so I cannot use any solution that requires being online.

Looking forward to your solutions, please.

Thanks ^^